# Routing AngularJs / Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, routes, laravel-routing, page-refresh

I got some problems using Laravel and Angular.

There my route.php

```
route.php

Route::group(array('domain' => 'dev.sydif.com'), function()
{
   Route::get('/' , 'IndexController@index');
   Route::get('/product' , 'IndexController@index');
   Route::get('/aboutus' , 'IndexController@index');
   Route::get('/product' , 'IndexController@index');
   Route::get('/signup' , 'IndexController@index');
   Route::get('/myproduct' , 'MyProductController@index');
});
```

My Angular modules

```
application.js

sydifApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider' ,
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'public_html/template/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        user_role: 0
    }).when('/aboutus', {
        templateUrl: 'public_html/template/aboutUs.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        user_role: 0
    }).when('/product', {
        templateUrl: 'public_html/template/product.html',
        controller: 'ProductCtrl',
        user_role: 0
    }).when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'public_html/template/signUp.html',
        controller: 'SignUpCtrl',
        user_role: 0
    }).when('/myproduct', {
        templateUrl: 'public_html/template/myProduct.html',
        controller: 'MyProductCtrl',
        user_role: 0
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

So when I came first on each route it works I see the pages. However for the Controller **MyProductController** i put a var dump like this :

```
MyProductController.php

public function index()
    {
        var_dump('expression');
        return View::make('index');
    }
```

What is the problem : When I go to the url **/myproduct** it's look like the Controller MyProductController is not loaded because i can't see the var_dump(). When I refresh the pages then the var_dump is visible. I am using ng-view inside the index.php and I have separated the back-end from the front-end.

Do you have any idea why my Controller is not load first?

I try to be as clear as possible.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is the expected result...you defined `/myproduct` route in angular as well as in Laravel, so when you request `/myproduct` from another route, Angular will look if that route is already pre-defined, if so -in this case it is- angular will simply load the according (template - controller) without refreshing the page forth requesting Laravel route.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So if I want to refresh the route and using the controller I must use an other way?

Comment: You can try `$rootScope.$on('$routeUpdate', function() {$route.reload();});`

Comment: Hum looks like I didn't pass inside the $route update so the route is not reload. Maybe a doing it wrong by using ng-view for this case?

Comment: yeah i think so, you either use Laravel routing or Angular routing....not both.